# Request additional Oauth2 scopes in Spring Security

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Say that I'm engaging my new users gradually, offering them a way to log in using Spring Security Oauth2 + Google (or any Oauth2 provider), and then somewhere down the road offering them a chance to add features that require additional Oauth2 scopes (say connecting calendar).

I have a naive working solution that involves making each set of scopes into a pseudo-provider in Spring Security Oauth2. Something like this (please forgive the Kotlin):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class WebSecurityConfig: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
    }

    @Bean
    open fun clientRegistrationRepository(): ClientRegistrationRepository {
        return InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(googleClientRegistration(), googleWithCalendarClientRegistration())
    }

    private fun googleClientRegistration(): ClientRegistration {
        // basic profile info
        return CommonOAuth2Provider.GOOGLE.getBuilder("google")
                .build()
    }

    private fun googleWithCalendarClientRegistration(): ClientRegistration {
        // profile info with calendar
        return CommonOAuth2Provider.GOOGLE.getBuilder("google-with-calendar")
                .registrationId("google-with-calendar")
                .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/google")
                .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "calendar.readonly")
                .build()
    }
}
```

I can then link my user to `https://www.example.com/oauth2/authorization/google-with-calendar` and Spring Security faithfully re-authorizes the user with the calendar scope added on.

But what if I have a second, then a third feature, each of which adds a scope, and each of which can be combined with any other set of features? I'm going to have to create a new pseudo-provider for not just every feature, but for every *combination* of features.

I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666965/incremental-authorization-for-google-oauth2-sign-in-with-spring-security), which is interesting but feels only slightly less of a hack than my current solution.

Is there a more idiomatic way to request an additional scope in Spring Security Oauth2?

Comment: Did you figure out a better solution?  I am facing the same situation now and will appreciate if you can share some experiences